# parse and decode mail text in aiosmtpd, perform string substitution, and reinject

Tags: python, email, smtp, email-attachments, aiosmtpd

I began with **smtpd** in order to process mailqueue, parse inbound emails and send them back to recipients (using **smtpdlib.sendmail**).
I switched to **aiosmtpd** since i needed multithread processing (while **smtpd** is single-threaded, and besides that looks like discontinued).

By the way I'm puzzled by **aiosmtpd** management of mail **envelope contents**, that seems much more granular than before, so good if you need really fine tuning, but somewhat oversized if you just want to process body without modifying the rest.

To make an example, smtpd **process_message** method just needed **data_decode=True** parameter to process and decode mail body without touching anything, while aiosmtpd **HANDLE_data** method seems unable to *automagically* decode mail envelope and often gives exceptions with embedded images, attachments, and so on...

**EDIT** added code examples, smtpd first: following code will instantiate smtp server waiting for mail on port 10025 and delivering to 10027 via smtplib (both localhost). It is safe to work on **data** variable (basically perform string substitutions, my goal) for all kind of mail (text/html based, with embedded images, attachments...)

```
class PROXY_SMTP(smtpd.SMTPServer):
        def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, decode_data=True):
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 10027)
        server.sendmail(mailfrom, rcpttos, data)
        server.quit()
server = PROXY_SMTP(('127.0.0.1', 10025), None)
asyncore.loop()
```

Previous code works well but in a single thread fashion (= 1 mail at once), so i switched to aiosmtpd to have concurrent mail processing. Same example with aiosmtpd would be roughly:

```
class MyHandler:
        async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
                peer = session.peer
                mailfrom = envelope.mail_from
                rcpttos = envelope.rcpt_tos
                data = envelope.content.decode()
                server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 10027)
                server.sendmail(mailfrom, rcpttos, data)
                server.quit()

my_handler = MyHandler()

async def main(loop):
        my_controller = Controller(my_handler, hostname='127.0.0.1', port=10025)
        my_controller.start()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main(loop=loop))
try:
     loop.run_forever()
```

This code works well for text emails, but will give exceptions when decoding envelope.content with any complex mail (mime content, attachments...)

How could I parse and decode mail text in aiosmtpd, perform string substitution as I did with smtpd, and reinject via smtplib?

Comment: Decode and parse how? Can you show an example?

Comment: Added relevant examples

Comment: I'm not familiar with this platform, but it seems that the thing you call "envelope contents" is not part of the envelope at all; it is the actual message. Decoding it seems like an odd thing to do; should you not simply be passing it on without attempting to decode it?

Comment: I need to perform string substitution on inbound mail, so i need to decode, modify and then reinject. 
I call it "envelope data" because this is what it's called like in docs, i agree with terminology but could not find specific class methods for body.

Comment: So then parse into an `email` object, modify it, and call `smtplib.send_message()` on the modified object? Alternatively, decode, manage it yourself, and then encode it again before passing it to the legacy `sendmail` method.

Comment: i hoped about a builtin method like old smtpd did, nonetheless it's a possibility, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One of the points of my answer is that you can't know what `message_to_string` produces. For example, if you are trying to replace "you" with "me", you need to cope with "y=\nou" and "yo=\n" too if the message is encoded using quoted-printable, and in the general case additionall a large number of base64 variations. And of course, the replacement cannot break the encapsulation. The only sane solution to my mind is to normalize the message into an `email` object and then convert it back when you are done.

Comment: But you don't need to convert it explicitly; `sendmail` does indeed only accept a string or bytes object, but it's a legacy method which you don't have to use; in fact if anything, I'd recommend you switch to the modern `send_message` if only because it encapsulates a little bit more of this back and forth manipulation.

Comment: you're right, damn i read it 10k times and still believed to read old sendmail instead of send_message. will come to a point and cleanup post.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `decode()` on something whose encoding you can't possibly know or predict in advance. Modifying the raw RFC5322 message is extremely problematic anyway, because you can't easily look inside quoted-printable or base64 body parts if you want to modify the contents. Also watch out for RFC2047 encapsulation in human-visible headers, file names in RFC2231 (or some dastardly non-compliant perversion - many clients don't get this even almost right) etc.  See below for an example.

Instead, if I am guessing correctly what you want, I would parse it into an `email` object, then take it from there.

```py
from email import message_from_bytes
from email.policy import default

class MyHandler:
    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        peer = session.peer
        mailfrom = envelope.mail_from
        rcpttos = envelope.rcpt_tos
        message = message_from_bytes(envelope.content, policy=default)
        # ... do things with the message,
        # maybe look into the .walk() method to traverse the MIME structure
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 10027)
        server.send_message(message, mailfrom, rcpttos)
        server.quit()
        return '250 OK'
```

The `policy` argument selects the modern `email.message.EmailMessage` class which replaces the legacy `email.message.Message` class from Python 3.2 and earlier. (A lot of online examples still promote the legacy API; the new one is more logical and versatile, so you want to target that if you can.)

This also adds the missing `return` statement which each handler should provide as per [the documentation.](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aiosmtpd/docs/handlers.html)

---

Here's an example message which contains the string "Hello" in two places. Because the content-transfer-encoding obscures the content, you need to analyze the message (such as by parsing it into an `email` object) to be able to properly manipulate it.

```
From: me <me@example.org>
To: you <recipient@example.net>
Subject: MIME encapsulation demo
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary="covfefe"

--covfefe
Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

You had me at "H=
ello."

--covfefe
Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PHRpdGxlPkhlbGxvLCBpcyBpdCBtZSB5b3UncmUgbG9va2luZyBmb3I/PC
90aXRsZT48L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHk+PHA+VGhlIGNvdiBpbiB0aGUgZmUgZmU8L3A+PC9ib2R5Pjwv
aHRtbD4K

--covfefe--
```

Comment: Looks like a good way. 
Just tried but can't get it to work, i'll try to study this class and eventually ask for further help. Thanks

Comment: Updated and tested with exact code provided, removed all string/text processing, getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'"

Comment: Without a traceback, hard to say. Which variable ends up containing `None`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiosmtpd/smtp.py", line 315, in _handle_client
    await method(arg)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiosmtpd/smtp.py", line 710, in smtp_DATA
    await self.push('250 OK' if status is MISSING else status)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiosmtpd/smtp.py", line 221, in push
    status + '\r\n', 'utf-8' if self.enable_SMTPUTF8 else 'ascii')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Thanks but it's not that. "return 250" was already there, i did not report it for simplicity, my bad. There was another problem: 1 order of parameters, and 2 smtplib.send accepting only string or bytes types as "message"

Comment: There is no `smtplib.send` and the `send_message` accepts an `email` message. Maybe post a separate answer with your fixes if you figured it out.

Comment: ... Or feel free to edit this answer if the changes are not too drastic.

Comment: yes i'm testing it and then editing with my final code, thanks for all the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The OP incorrectly added this text to the question; I'm moving it here as a (half) answer.

**--- SOLVED ---**

This is what i gotten so far, minor adjustments are still needed (mainly for mime content separate handling and "rebuilding") but this solves my main problem: **receive mail on separated threads, make room for text processing, sleep for fixed amount of time before final delivery**. Thanks to tripleee answers and comments I found correct way.

```
import asyncio
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
import smtplib
from email import message_from_bytes
from email.policy import default
class MyHandler:
    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        peer = session.peer
        mailfrom = envelope.mail_from
        rcpttos = envelope.rcpt_tos
        message = message_from_bytes(envelope.content, policy=default)
        #HERE MAYBE WOULD BE SAFER TO WALK CONTENTS AND PARSE/MODIFY ONLY MAIL BODY, BUT NO SIDE EFFECTS UNTIL NOW WITH MIME, ATTACHMENTS...
        messagetostring = message.as_string() ### smtplib.sendmail WANTED BYTES or STRING, NOT email OBJECT.
        ### HERE HAPPENS TEXT PROCESSING, STRING SUBSTITUTIONS...
        ### THIS WAS MY CORE NEED, ASYNCWAIT ON EACH THREAD
        await asyncio.sleep(15)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 10027)
        server.send_message(mailfrom, rcpttos, messagetostring) ### NEEDED TO INVERT ARGS ORDER
        server.quit()
        return '250 OK' ### ADDED RETURN
    
 my_handler = MyHandler()
    
 async def main(loop):
        my_controller = Controller(my_handler, hostname='127.0.0.1', port=10025)
        my_controller.start()
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 loop.create_task(main(loop=loop))
 try:
        loop.run_forever()
```